# No "Going?" response options visible in Google Calendar event invitations

Tags: google-calendar

I created a Google calendar, added some events to it, and then invited a group of people --- some with GMail addresses, most with other accounts --- to attend via the "Guests" option for that event.

They all got the invite, but in almost all cases, only responded to me by e-mail, rather than clicking one of the "Yes", "Maybe", "No" options in their invite. On further investigation, it seems that these options aren't appearing in their e-mails at all.

I tried sending invites to two other accounts I maintain (one GMail, one Yahoo), and the options did appear for me.

Any ideas?